# I cannot seem to split a file

Tags: split

I have a txt file with 42804563 lines. I would like to split it into files with 1000 lines each.

I tried using:

```
split -l 1000 myfile splitted
```

The error message I get is:

`split: Output file suffixes exhausted`

Comment: See the manual page for `split`. It uses a fixed format method for enumerating output files. You are looking to generate `42804563 / 1000` or `42805` output files, and that number is larger than the scheme `split` uses can acommodate.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of a different command I can use?

Comment: One way to do this would be to split into a smaller number of files, then split the resulting files recursively. So do a `split -l 100000 myfile splitted`, then script a `for` loop to do your `splitted` subfiles to length 1000. Or use `awk`.

Comment: I increased it to 100000 and it worked. I can then split those if I need to into smaller parts. Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Since `split` uses two alphabet characters to distinguish output files, the total number of output files it can handle is maximum 26x26, or 676.

Comment: I noticed that csplit seems to offer an ability to create a suffix. Basically, I would like to have the output suffix aa.txt, ab.txt, ac.txt, ad.txt.... Can you provide me an example for csplit? I was using csplit {100000} myfile -f splitted_myfile -b %.txt and it gives me 'csplit: missing conversion specifier in suffix'

Comment: Also, if you click on Answer Your Question, then I can mark your answer as Answered so it gives you reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "more" or "less" command and redirect the output to your new files.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker answered my question.

I used:

```
split 100000 myfile splitted_myfile.
```

And, my output were files with 100000 lines each with a splitted_myfile.[a-z] extension.